# Windows Search Limits Queries to 255 Chars. Any Way to Override This?

Tags: windows-8, windows-search, desktop-search

I run Windows 8 and have run into an issue... As you know, Windows features a "fuzzy" search, which is great for finding multiple files... However, I often have to search for multiple files using a massive search string (usually ~500 characters, sometimes more) that comes from the support system at my company. Since Windows search limits you to 255 characters, I have to break my string into several searches.

This doesn't make much sense to me. I know that Windows limits file names to 255 characters (+ a null terminator), but I'm searching for multiple files. I found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) which discusses the MAX_PATH variable, which explains the file length limit, but I'm not searching for just **one** file.

I'm kind of at a loss because this is really impacting the efficiency of my workflow... Search strings should NOT be truncated after 255 characters, especially since we do have the ability to search for multiple files at once... **Anyone have any ideas on how to "override" this restriction?**

**tl;dr** Windows limits fuzzy search to 255 characters. I need to search for longer strings than 255 characters. Halp!

[reddit post w/ some extra details in comments if you need it](http://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/18pe4o/windows_search_limited_to_255_characters_why/)

Answer (score 0):

When you save a search it gets saved as a **.search-ms** file, which is an XML-based format that's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

One option could be to manually edit the XML or dynamically generate it to include all your query strings.