# Limit of files and/or length of "name:" search boolean query in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

What is the limit of to how long a query like `'name:("name1.txt" OR "name2.txt" OR ...)'` can be for Windows Explorer search bar? Or, in which Windows documentation can one find that info?

I have small lists of files (30/40 in no) which I need to see from the large folder. One of the list I took to construct a query (with 19 long filenames, total length of query 4154 chars). It worked on that list, but on a larger set it fails, so there is some limit at play here (not sure whether it's the number of files or query length.

(This is a follow up to the comment for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1594528/show-only-specific-files-in-the-folder-view-of-windows-explorer).) Hope I'm not inadvertently committing a SE crime by turning it into a question!

Comment: @Moab Isn't that for a browser? Does that apply to Windows Explorer (aka file explorer) as well?

Comment: Evidently it is 255 characters>>>https://superuser.com/questions/554975/windows-search-limits-queries-to-255-chars-any-way-to-override-this

Comment: @Moab Well, as I wrote in my question, I've already performed a 4154 char long query... so it appears it is larger than 255 chars, no?

Comment: Maybe 255 is the limit on that specific search, try a search less than 255 on that same set you get an error on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out how many files it will accept:

My trials:

- **Windows 7:** `35` filenames in the query (total query length was `1798` characters long, and as mentioned in question, I have already done a query with `4154` chars but with larger names and fewer files (so it appears the length does not matter, the number of files does). Though I do have a feeling that the 4145 char long query might've been a mistake, in counting the length properly and it could've been shorter, but anyway, it's the number of filenames that matter anyway apparently
- **Windows 10:** Won't even accept a query longer than 518 in my trial with 35 name query pasted in the box (truncates), so make whatever of that, if you will.